# sales_order_place_after event dispatch if payment gateway decline credit card

Tags: magento, paypal

I  am using paypal express creditcard as payment method. but when payment gateway decline. At that time sales_order_place_after event will fire?
I want to know when sales_order_place_after event going to be dispatch.